# Installing mongodb extension mac os

Tags: php, macos, mongodb

Hey All trying to install MongoDb extension on my Mac OSx 10.9.5. I installed php 5.6 using `brew install php56`, now this php version is used, then I installed mongodb using  `brew install php56-mongodb`

When now do php -v i get this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.21 (cli) (built: Apr 29 2016 02:31:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I also enabled a `extension=mongodb.so` in my php --ini, I followed the path in the error and its breaks at `extensions` directory its does not exist instead `build` directory is there.

I dont understand what what is trying to call this path and why the path is brocken if it is a fresh install...?

Answer (score 1):

"extension=mongodb.so" is not on it's right place in your php.ini file it should be under the extentions

Comment: does it really answer the question?

Comment: it solved the problem for me, i figured out  "extension=mongodb.so" was also written in the bottom of my php.ini file, and i removed it, then it worked and i was able to install mongo